# Why does my C# analyzer not display messages (DiagnosticSeverity.Info)

Tags: c#, roslyn-code-analysis

Recently started messing around with C# analyzers and generators, and I had to find out that reported diagnostics show up fine when using `DiagnosticSeverity.Warning` or `DiagnosticSeverity.Error`, but not at all with `DiagnosticSeverity.Info`.

External analyzers seem to report messages just fine, so I wonder what I am doing wrong.

```
using System.Collections.Immutable;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics;

namespace Sssl.Messaging.Analyzers;

[DiagnosticAnalyzer("C#")]
public class DummyAnalyzer : DiagnosticAnalyzer
{
    private static readonly DiagnosticDescriptor TypeFoundDiagnostic = new
        ("SSSL001", "Named Type Found", "Found Named Type {0}", "Info", DiagnosticSeverity.Warning, true);

    public override ImmutableArray<DiagnosticDescriptor> SupportedDiagnostics =>
        ImmutableArray.Create(TypeFoundDiagnostic);

    public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
    {
        context.EnableConcurrentExecution();
        context.ConfigureGeneratedCodeAnalysis(GeneratedCodeAnalysisFlags.Analyze | GeneratedCodeAnalysisFlags.ReportDiagnostics);
        context.RegisterSymbolAction(AnalyzeSymbol, SymbolKind.NamedType);
    }

    private static void AnalyzeSymbol(SymbolAnalysisContext context)
    {
        context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(TypeFoundDiagnostic, Location.None, context.Symbol.Name));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's by design according to [GeneratorExecutionContext.ReportDiagnostic prints nothing when DiagnosticSeverity is set to Info in source generator](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/50574).

Related Proposal: logging APIs for source generators
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/50208